# How to load a different div on reload (in repeating order)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, reload

I've saw this code on the internet:

```
$(function(){
    $(".various"+(new Date().getTime() % 3)).css("display", "block");
});
```

It changes the div which is visible on reload in a random order. I only have one problem whit this, in my case this looks very unprofessional. So my question is how can I make this not random but that it first show up div1, second reload div2, third reload div3 and than back to div1, I'm a pretty noob in javascript so a hole new peace of javascript is also fine

Thanks, Sake

Comment: How would you keep track of which div to show if you're reloading the whole page each time?

Comment: I think you want to create a kind of slideshow for your divs, am I right ? and btw the code you posted seems too much to jQuery for me. Please add your html code.

Comment: Yes, I want a slideshow but it only have to change on page reload in a repeating order, this is jquery but javascript is also oke

Comment: Cookies (almost all browsers and versions) or localStorage (see compatibility here: http://quirksmode.org/html5/index.html)  will work for you. For handling cookies with jQuery see: http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/

Also with PHP/ASPX you could try a session based approach to load/render a diff div (if you're using sessions).

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to change the div when the page is loaded (this means not having a slideshow running for your divs,changing your html to hide/show them)

I can think on 3 approachs:

**1)** You can try as the previous answer (from @Charlie) use cookies to store the current div.

- You can try handle cookie with pure javascript, or better yet
- Since you're already using jquery take a look to this nice post and the $.cookie plugin for jQuery:
  http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/

This has the advantage of working in old browsers (and jquery will take care of **crossbrowsing**)

**UPDATE An example Using cookies with jQuery (jquery.cookie plugin)**

After your jQuery add the [`jquery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">  </script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"> </script>
```

Suppose we/you have this html divs:

```
//Notice the divs are using a prefixed id with numeric ending
//(I think it's the best option)

<div id="mdiv1">
    <ul><li><a href="#" id="mlink"> hello 1 </a></li></ul>
</div>


<div id="mdiv2">
    <ul><li><a href="#" id="mlink"> hello 2</a></li></ul>
</div>


<div id="mdiv3">
    <ul><li><a href="#" id="mlink"> hello 3</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

And this the jQuery Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //hide all divs just for the purpose of this example, 
    //you should have the divs hidden with your css

    $('#mdiv1').hide();
    $('#mdiv2').hide();
    $('#mdiv3').hide();
    //check if the cookie is already setted
    if ($.cookie("currentDiv")===undefined){
            $.cookie("currentDiv",1);
    }else{ //else..well 
            //get and increment value, let's suppse we have just 3 divs     

            var numValue = parseInt($.cookie("currentDiv"));
            numValue = numValue + 1;
            if (numValue>3){
            //restart to 1
                $.cookie("currentDiv",1);
            }
            else{ //no issues, assign the incremented value
                $.cookie("currentDiv",numValue.toString());
            }

            //show the div
            $('#mdiv'+$.cookie("currentDiv")).show();
    }
});
</script>
```

**2)** As @Ra Mon commented, localStorage is another nice option (modern browsers) to keep track of the last loaded div.

I think it's more elegant than cookies, but it has the **drawback** of not working on oldbrowsers, of course you can use [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) to feature detections and apply some [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) (use cookies) **to get crossbrowsing.**

**3)** A third approach (as long as you don't need "dynamic" html) I would like to mention is using server side sessions (php/aspx) to keep track of the last div loaded/rendered and render the next one. Even you could handle the cookies from server side if don't want to use memory based sessions, the **drawback** will be the lost of caching.

Try some code and back to update your question with more and/or specific details so someone be able to help you whatever the approach you choose.

@RyanS I meant:

**About "dynamic"** if you're going to change the div only when the page is loaded, then there's no need of using clientSide scripting, this can be achieved from server side.

**About "caching"**, if you're going to change the page/html in the server side, the webserver will have to "serve" the web page again to the WebBrowser/Client since it change from the last viewed (lost of cache, add a bit of load traffic, bandwidth usage) <<< better said, if the browser determines that the page has change since the last viewed (and will be) will request the html/page again.

Comment: can you expand on your points about losing dynamic html and caching for the 3rd approach?

Comment: Hi @RyanS Expanded/updated, it's about losing cache and need or don't need "dynamic" html.

Comment: Ok gotcha, I thought you meant caching images, which would be unaffected. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Cookies to save the current div number that is visible.

Read this on how to set and retrieve cookies : [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

After you got the current div number (for example the name is `divNum`, run this function

```
 function showDiv() {
      $("#div" + divNum).show();

      divNum++;
      //Remember to set the divNum back to the cookies for later use
 }
```

I'm not a pro so maybe there's a better way to handle this..
CMIIW~